# Signal R - Failed writing message. Aborting connection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I have a .Net Core 2.2 Web API that is using Signal R 1.1.0.  I have been getting lately many errors in my service logs as below.  I have been trying things in my startup file liking setting the keepAlive etc. but no dice it keeps coming up and my angular client freezes up on me.  Any idea how I can troubleshoot this better?   Also showing my startup setting I just tried with the keep alive.

Errors:

```
Failed writing message. Aborting connection.
System.InvalidOperationException: Writing is not allowed after writer was completed.
   at System.IO.Pipelines.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException_NoWritingAllowed()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetMemory(Int32 sizeHint)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeWriter.GetSpan(Int32 sizeHint)
   at System.Buffers.BuffersExtensions.Write[T](IBufferWriter`1 writer, ReadOnlySpan`1 value)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeWriter.WriteAsync(ReadOnlyMemory`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.HubConnectionContext.WriteCore(SerializedHubMessage message)
```

Startup file:

```
services.AddSignalR(hubOptions => {
        hubOptions.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
        hubOptions.KeepAliveInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
    })
    .AddJsonProtocol(options =>
    {
        options.PayloadSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
    });
```

Comment: Could you please tell me which hub method throw this error? It seems that you have created a writer that write something to your server or else. Please post more details information.